# Difference between x + x and 2*x in Java

Tags: java, integer-overflow

I was reading the answers to a Leetcode problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/divide-two-integers/. This problem requires not using multiplication. After reading a few answers, I somehow had a misconception that `x+x` is better than `2*x` in terms of memory and avoiding type overflow. After post the question, I cannot find any evidence to support this statement. Please ignore this question.

---

I saw a common practice in Java is using x + x instead of 2*x especially for int. For example

```
int x = 1;
x += x;
```

Instead of

```
int x = 1;
x = 2*x;
```

Using

```
if (a < b + b) {
  ...
}
```

Instead of

```
if (a < 2*b) {
  ...
}
```

Does `x + x` save slightly more memory than `2*x`?

Comment: Where did you saw that ? Can you share a link of example ?

Comment: "Is there any data type overflow concern for 2*x?" Yes, but it's exactly the same as for `x + x`.

Comment: I'm surprised it isn't using `x << 1`.  But at a guess "2" is just one more constant for the constants table, and `x` is already a value in memory.

Comment: @markspace I struggle to believe the difference would be relevant.

Comment: You can probably run a few tests and track wall time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems more like a habit than has any reason to use this convention, unless JVM is more efficient in carrying our + operation than *, which probably is something we can totally ignore